# Why IPAddress.Any needs to connect to remote host?

Tags: c#, tcp, tcplistener

I'm building one client server application in c# where server is remote host. I've router and firewall in my network.

My client side code is

```
hostSocket = new TcpClient();                
hostSocket.Connect(serverIp, serverPort);
```

And My server side code was

`eqListner = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(eqIp), eqPort);`

in this scenario I'm able to connect client on same pc by giving ip 127.0.0.1 but cannot connect when I ran server on another pc in my network.

Then I've changed my server side code by following:

```
IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint ipLocalEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, eqPort);
TcpListener eqListner = new TcpListener(ipLocalEndPoint);
```

But still the result is same. Then I changed my server side code again by this:

`eqListner = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, eqPort);`

And this works perfectly fine. I've read msdn for `IPAddress.Any` and found that this property set server to listen for client activity on all network interfaces.

My question is why IPAddress.Any needs to connect to remote host? and other functions cannot connects?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

> in this scenario I'm able to connect client on same pc by giving ip 127.0.0.1 but cannot connect when I ran server on another pc in my network

`127.0.0.1` is the loopback address that is always the local host. When the service and the client are only on the same machine this can be convenient.

You are better off coding services to listen on all interfaces, this way should the server change address your application doesn't need to be updated or restarted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in the first line.

```
IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList[0];
```

It will get the first ip of the host were it is running. That may be a IPv6 or localhost address.
If you want to listen in a specific address, it will be better to add it to [project settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). It will be stored in app.config, and you can change it without recompile.

Comment: I'm asking importance of `IPAddress.Any`. Anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: `IPAddress.Any` will accept connections from any interface. That why it works. If you are listen `AddressList[0]` and it can't be accessed from outside the host (because is IPv6 and IPv6 isn't configured in your network, or because it is a loopback, ...), clients will never be able to connect.